# C program for printing the initial letters of words from a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm attempting to write a C program to print the initials of an end-users name using strings and pointers. I've written in comments what I think the function needs to do for illustration.

Here's my progress so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH 31 

char userInitials(char *name)
{
    // Initialize the character array "name" and set to zero
    // Determine the length of the string using strlen
    // Print the first valid input of the string
    // Loop through the string until a space is found
    // When a space is found, print the next valid input  

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        name[i] = 0;
    }

    int length = strlen(name);

    if (name[0] != ' ' && name[0] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c\n", name[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 < length && name[i + 1] != ' ')
        {
            printf("%c\n", name[i + 1]);
        }
    }
}

char main()
{
    char name[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH] = " ";

    printf("Enter your full name and I'll print your initials: ");
    scanf_s("%[^\n]", &name, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH);
    printf("Your name is: %c\n", name);
    printf("Your initials are: %c\n", userInitials(name));
}
```

My program is currently stuck at line 42:

```
printf("Your initials are: %s\n", userInitials(name));
```

Visual Studio is returning an error message:

```
(42): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'.
```

I'm also not sure if the function will work, either, because there's an error on line 33 that I don't understand (I'm posting lines 26-33 for illustration):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (i + 1 < length && name[i + 1] != ' ')
        {
            printf("%c\n", name[i + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio is returning an error message: *(33): warning C4716: 'userInitials': must return a value*.

I'm really struggling to get this working and my instructors aren't very good at explaining how to solve error messages. I would be very grateful for your time and help.

Comment: Check the formatting of your question. I am sure you lost at least one  `* ` to markdown.

Comment: I'm sorry, but (newbie question) I don't understand.

Comment: Compare the message you actually get at home with the message everybody else sees in your question. There is an important difference.

Comment: Enclose the message inside backwards upper ticks: `\``

Comment: I think you need to read about [C4716](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ft5xye74(v=vs.140)) "'userInitials': must return a value." - it should clarify things...

Comment: @Yunnosch getting function to return something meaningful may be a good start... Everyone learns differently and that is just another option...

Comment: I edited your question (using a different methdo) to make the actual message visible. Please double check that the message now seen is the one you actually get at home.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, you might be right. Answering both parts in one go is probably best. Thanks. I will update my answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Your link seems helpful for the second part. Would you mind if I add it to my answer? For completeness purposes, I will give credit of course.

Comment: @Yunnosch sure:) no need for credit - its first link on https://www.bing.com/search?q=C4716

Comment: Whoever close-voted for lack of MCVE, please explain.

Comment: hailnolly, it seems you did not yet find the help you were hoping for. What is it that is missing for you?

Comment: @Yunnosch - thank you for explaining and clarifying the formatting issue in my question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - thank you for sharing the link with me. It was useful to help me understand the problem and what the compiler is looking for

Comment: @Yunnosch what's missing, I think, is how to ask the program to return the characters to print.

Comment: `main()` shall return `int` not `char`!

Answer (score 1):

Printf format string parameter `%s` requires a pointer to char.
Your function returns a single char (not a pointer),
at least the prototype promisses so, even if the code then does not.
The message tells you so quite clearly.

In order to print a single char, use `%c`.

The fact that your function `userInitials()` does not return anything, because it does not contain a single `return`statement, is the reason for the second part of your question.
AlexeiLevenkov (in a comment above) provided a useful link to Microsoft content discussing this mistake, with example of a function with a commented `return`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ft5xye74(v=vs.140)

*(By the way, only asking about one problem at a time is more appreciated here at StackOverflow. Questions asking about more than one thing are at risk of getting closed for being too broad.)*

Comment: I understand now why the string parameters were incorrectly coded. I need to figure out what return statement to use, now, as we haven't covered those.

Answer (score 1):

The initials should be either printed from `userInitials()` or returned to `main()` to be printed there. Not both.

Consider declaring `userInitials()` with a return type that can hold more than one `char`, e.g. by introducing a data structure that holds both initials

```c
struct initials {
  char first;
  char last;
};
```

and adjusting the function signature accordingly:

```c
struct initials userInitials(const char *name)
```